# How could I save dataset from ipython notebook in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: python, azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I use next command to save output results:

```
ws.datasets.add_from_dataframe(data, 'GenericCSV', 'output.csv', 'Uotput results')
```

where `ws` is `azureml.Workspace` object and `data` is `pandas.DataFrame`.

It works fine if my dataset size less than 4 mb. Otherwise I got a error:

```
AzureMLHttpError: Maximum request length exceeded.
```

As I understood this is the error raised by Azure environment limits and the maximum size of the dataset could not be changed.

I could split my dataset to 4 mb parts and download them from Azure ML studio, but it is very inconvinient if size of my output dataset is more than 400 mb.

Comment: Going to bounce this question around internally and see if I can get you any advice... I would say this is not acting as expected....

Comment: Are you using the notebook service within AML, or a local IPython Notebook with the AzureML Python SDK?

Comment: I am using the notebook service within AML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have read the source code in the python package **azureml**, and found out that they are using a simple request post when uploading a dataset, which has a limited content length 4194304 bytes.

I tried to modify the code inside "http.py" within the python package **azureml**. I posted the request with a chunked data, and I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\azuremltest.py", line 10, in <module>
    ws.datasets.add_from_dataframe(frame, 'GenericCSV', 'output2.csv', 'Uotput results')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azureml\__init__.py", line 507, in add_from_dataframe
    return self._upload(raw_data, data_type_id, name, description)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azureml\__init__.py", line 550, in _upload
raw_data, None)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azureml\http.py", line 135, in upload_dataset
    upload_result = self._send_post_req(api_path, raw_data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azureml\http.py", line 197, in _send_post_req
    raise AzureMLHttpError(response.text, response.status_code)
azureml.errors.AzureMLHttpError: Chunked transfer encoding is not permitted. Upload size must be indicated in the Content-Length header.
Request ID: 7b692d82-845c-4106-b8ec-896a91ecdf2d 2016-03-14 04:32:55Z
```

The REST API in **azureml** package does not support chunked transfer encoding. Hence, I took a look at how the Azure ML studio implements this, and I found out this:

1. It post a request with content-length=0 to `https://studioapi.azureml.net/api/resourceuploads/workspaces/<workspace_id>/?userStorage=true&dataTypeId=GenericCSV`, which will return an id in the response body.
2. Break the .csv file into chunks less than 4194304 bytes, and post them to `https://studioapi.azureml.net/api/blobuploads/workspaces/<workspace_id>/?numberOfBlocks=<the number of chunks>&blockId=<index of chunk>&uploadId=<the id you get from previous request>&dataTypeId=GenericCSV`

If you really want this functionality, you can implement it with python and the above REST API.

If you think it's too complicated, report the issue to [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python/issues). The **azureml** python package is still under development, so your suggestion would be very helpful for them.

Comment: Thanks. It is a little complicated for me, but I'll try to implement it by myself. Anyway I create the issue about this problem.

Comment: I've created a pull request which fixes this based upon Jack's sluthing - https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python/pull/29

Comment: And now it's fixed in the 0.2.7 release of the SDK

Comment: Thank you, @Dino Veihland. I have used your code from github and It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

According to AzureML project on Github, the `Workspace` Object `ws` works via HTTP request for Azure Resource Management. SO your code is a resoure manager API request. The error `AzureMLHttpError` was caused by overing the limitation for Azure Resource Manager API request size. The maximum limit size is **4194304 bytes**.

You can find it in the section `Subscription limits - Azure Resource Manager` of the doc [`Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/), please see the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I could not use `Workspace` object to save my data. Is there another method?

Answer (score 0):

Alexey, You might write to Azure Blob Storage, but I find methods to do so very sparsely documented.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/